# Different methods for finding matrix of a linear map $f$ with respect to a different basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I learnt the two methods in both examples below separately and so I'm a little confused as to how they relate, when one works over the other, etc.

**Example 1:**

Suppose the linear map $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ has associated matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix} -13 & 49 \\ -4 & 15\end{pmatrix}$$ with respect to the basis $B=\left\{(1,0)^T,(0,1)^T\right\}$. We want to find the matrix of $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ with respect to a different basis $B'=\left\{(3,1)^T,(7,2)^T\right\}$.

So the two methods I've considered (and forgive me for missing out the transpose part, which I've done for simplicity) are as follows:

*Method 1: Linear combinations*

We know $f(1,0)=(-13,-4)$ and $f(0,1)=(49,15).$

Then using the linearity of $f$, we have $f(3,1)=(10,3)=1(3,1)+1(7,2)$ and $f(7,2)=(7,2)=0(3,1)+1(7,2).$

*Method 2: Change of basis matrix* $P$ and finding the matrix $f$ wrt $B'$ by calculating $P^{-1}AP$. This is fairly simple so I will omit the details.

In both cases, we see that the matrix of $f$ with respect to the basis $B'$ is $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Ok so that worked out fine but in another example that I've tried, listed below, the change of basis method didn't work.

**Example 2:** (Edit: there appears to be confusion about this, probably because of my poor paraphrasing of the question so I have attached the exact question instead)

https://postimg.org/image/3k7h1glvz/ 
It's not too hard to do this using the linear combinations method but I couldn't get it to work using the change of basis method because the transition matrix $$P=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & i & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & i \end{pmatrix}$$ isn't invertible.

Does this fail because of the change in field, and if so is this is the only time where the change of basis formula won't work? How about if $f:U\rightarrow V$ is a linear map such that $U\neq V$? In other words, are the two methods generally interchangeable, when does one fail (and so when should I use one over the other)?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Thanks for the response. I'm a little confused by what you're suggesting though. Just to clarify, for the second example we're initially considering the linear map $f:V\rightarrow V$ where $V=\mathbb{C}^2$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and then we want to consider $V$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ instead and find a matrix for that wrt $B'$.

Answer (score 0):

In Ex. 2, the Set $B'$ is not a basis of $\mathbb C^2$ !!

Comment: It is when $V=\mathbb{C}^2$ is viewed as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

1. in Example 2, the Basis B is not a basis of  $ C^2 $ .
   That is where the problem lies.
2. Here , the matrix of linear transformation T:U-> V is actually dependent on the
   following factors.

i.  A basis of U(A) ii. A basis of V(B) and ii. The Common field F.

If we fix these three the Matrix representing the transformation is UNIQUE.

NOW,
Here You are considering A special case where U=V and most importantly

A=B.

In example 1. Have you noticed that your matrix p is a square matrix but  it is not in eg2.

It is because in example1. you have taken the basis of both $ R^2 $ but in case2 you have not taken  a proper basis of  $C^2 $ at first  hence it is 2x4 matrix if you have taken a proper basis it would have been 4x4 matrix because here you considered A=B.

I think it will be of some help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I do see where you're coming from but I'm still a bit confused about why all the replies say $B'$ is not a basis of $\mathbb{C}^2.$ This is taken directly from the lecturer's question sheet: 'Let $V=\mathbb{C}^2$ be viewed as a column vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $f:V\rightarrow V$ be the linear map represented by the matrix $A$ (as in original post) wrt the standard basis of $V$. Now consider $V$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. You may use without proof the fact that $B'=\{(1,0)^T,(i,0)^T,(0,1)^T,(0,i)^T\}$ is a basis of $V$.'

Comment: I did n't say B' is not a basis. b' is perfectly alright .But Please do compare the first example what you are doing with the second ,You will clearly understand why the 2nd case matrix is not coming to be square. Perhaps that is the point your professor wants to ask!!

Comment: I told B is not a Basis of $ C^2 $ . and your f has A domain of 4 C^2 $

Comment: I see. Fred said $B'$ is not a basis, and I might be misinterpreting things but the question specifically states that it is and with respect to your remark, $B$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{C}^2$, is it not?

Comment: B is not A standard basis of $ C^2 $ over $R^2$ . can you construct It?? Then Give an Example!

Comment: We are considering $V=\mathbb{C}^2$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ initially and then as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Where does $\mathbb{R}^2$ come from?

Comment: Sorry , that will be $R^2$.

Comment: There is the problem You can't change the field in between. the Definition of Linear transformation is valid iff we work with the same field always.

Comment: that will be $R$

Comment: Please see the exact question from the lecturer in case I've paraphrased poorly: https://postimg.org/image/3k7h1glvz/ NB: I have changed the notation slightly in this question writing $B$ for the standard basis and $B'$ for what's stated as $B$ in the question.

Comment: Actually the most important part of the question is that part which  your lecturer has tactfully asked you to assume.The part where You represent your initial vector space with respect to the new one. It is almost done i will post it tomorrow. Please see if this hint is helpful to you.

Comment: Please see this link .http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~franz/la05/compl.pdf

Comment: It might be helpful.Go through it  for the first 2 -3 paragraphs till you think it is relevant.